# How to init a "late" in a flutter widget without @immutable error

Tags: flutter

I have a widget

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  late List<ScrollItem> scrollerValues;
  MyWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.items})
      : super(key: key) {
    scrollerValues = items.map((e) => ScrollItem(e)).toList();
  }
  …
```

I have an error

```
This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: MyWidget.scrollerValues
```

How can I offer an API with a list of String in the constructor (because it's simple for the user) and keep a list of ScrollItem (because it's the internal need).

I know that I could move `late List<ScrollItem> scrollerValues;` in my state class, but I need it in the widget, because it's used by other methods in widget…

Comment: The error told you what's wrong: `scrollerValues` isn't `final`.  Declare it as `late final List<ScrollItem> scrollerValues;`. (Normally `final` members cannot be initialized in a constructor body, but there's an exception for `late` members.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is a warning. The reason comes from the fact that, StatelessWidgets are marked as immutable elements within the widget tree. These elements expect the class level variables to actually have an immutable value. This can be implemented with `final` or `const` keyword.

What you need to do is to add `final` to the scrollerValues.

The example below helps you out with the code explanation.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final List<String> items;
  late final List<ScrollItem> scrollerValues;
  
  MyWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.items,
  }) : super(key: key) {
    scrollerValues = items.map((e) => ScrollItem(e)).toList();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'Hello, World!',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
    );
  }
}

class ScrollItem {
  const ScrollItem(this.title);
  final String title;
}
```